# How to write Django REST Api without model to send a file using Requests

Tags: python, django, rest, python-requests

I want to write a rest method without model so that I can send a csv file using python requests module.
This csv file should be remotely accessed from the server.

For example - 
I have logged in to my project using requests and get the cookies and headers so that I can pass it to the following requests method..

```
files = {'file': open('test.csv', 'rb')}
response = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=api_headers,
                      cookies=api_cookies)
```

So this url should be : call for that rest method.

views.py file :

```
class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        csvfile = request.data['file']
        #reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        #for r in reader:
            #print(r)
        return Response(status=204)
```

Just to note - I am sending a csv file using requests module.

Can anyone please help me on how to write this rest method?

Comment: REST Api doesn't mean it need a Model. You can do normal views to accept the file.

Comment: so you want to upload a file using api and you would do some processing or what ever on the file in the View ?

Comment: @rrmerugu yes correct.

Comment: @itzmeontv Can you please give me an example?

Comment: Yup. it have direct doc http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser or you are not using drf ?

Comment: @itzmeontv Okay Thank you so much.

Comment: @SnehaShinde Did you check `FileUploadParser` and `Response` is imported ?

Comment: @itzmeontv Yes I have added both.

Comment: Dont you have log or DEBUG enabled ?

Comment: @itzmeontv Now I am getting 400:Bad request. I think the problem is with sending a response. when I print r.text,it returns: {"detail":"Missing filename. Request should include a Content-Disposition header with a filename parameter."}

Comment: @SnehaShinde I have updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normal django view

```
def myview(request):
    f = request.FILES['file']
    with open('some/folder/name.txt', 'wb+') as destination: 
        #f.name or f.filename (dont know which one)will get filename.So you can replace it name.txt
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
    return JsonResponse({"message": "Uploaded!"})
```

**UPDATE**

```
# views.py
class FileUploadView(views.APIView):
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)

    def post(self, request, filename, format=None):
        file_obj = request.data['file']
        # ...
        # do some stuff with uploaded file
        # ...
        return Response(status=200)

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^upload/(?P<filename>[^/]+)$', FileUploadView.as_view())
]
```

Then

```
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/test.csv' #filename should be in url
files = {'file': open('test.csv', 'rb')}
response = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=api_headers,
                      cookies=api_cookies)
```

Answer (score 3):

This would do the trick for you. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser

```
# views.py
class FileUploadView(views.APIView):
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)

    def post(self, request, filename, format=None):
        file_obj = request.data['file']
        # ...
        # do some stuff with uploaded file
        # ...
        return Response(status=204)

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^upload/(?P<filename>[^/]+)$', FileUploadView.as_view())
]

# test with this curl
curl -X POST -S -H -F "file=@something.jpg;type=image/jpg" 127.0.0.1:8000/upload/myfile/
```

Comment: I have created above function - and when I try to send a file using requests - files = {'file': open('test.pdf', 'rb')},
response = requests.post('127.0.0.1:8000/upload/', files=files, headers=api_headers,cookies=api_cookies). It gives me an 400 error:Bad request.Please check and help.

Comment: @SnehaShinde Then why did you accept that. Instead of `def put`, use `post`

Comment: @Sneha Can u post the log error if any from the console

Comment: @itzmeontv Sorry for that,I thought it will work.Anyway I tried replacing put with 'post'.but still it's giving the same error.Am I defining the url correctly - '127.0.0.1:8000/upload/'  to the requests?

Comment: @SnehaShinde try with `post(self, request, format=None)` if you are not sending filename in url

Comment: @rrmerugu No any log error.I am running a python program where I have written  this requests code which is mentioned above.

Comment: @itzmeontv Tried. this is how I mentioned in urls.py - url(r'^test_upload/$', FileUploadView.as_view()), and in requests - response = requests.post('127.0.0.1:8000/test_upload/', files=files, headers=api_headers,cookies=api_cookies). now it's giving 500:Internal server error.

Comment: @SnehaShinde can you post your `views.py` code ? 500 must be from some processing that you might be doing in views.py

Comment: @rrmerugu I have upadated a question with views.py file.please check.

Comment: Is this how you are calling the api ? `files = {'file': open('something.csv','rb')}
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_upload/', files=files, )`

Comment: @rrmerugu yes...Is there something wrong with it.actually I am new to DRF so please help if you can.:)