# Upload image file using django rest framework in a single page application

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to upload image using Vuejs and Django, but I can't figure out how to solve it.

This is the django side:

```
class UserDetail(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=create_file_path)

class UserDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserDetail
        fields = '__all__'

class UserDetailViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserDetail.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserDetailSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    @detail_route(permission_classes=[AllowAny], methods=['POST'], parser_classes=[FormParser, MultiPartParser])
    def create_or_update_profile_picture(self, request):
        user = request.user
        #
        # how to create or update user detail profile picture ?
        #
```

I am posting the data this way from Vuejs:

```
changeProfilePicture() {
    const file_input = document.getElementById('display_profile_image');
    const img = file_input.files[0];
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("profile_picture", img);
    const url = this.$store.state.website + '/api/accounts/user-detail/none/create_or_update_profile_picture/';
    this.$http.post(url, formData)
        .then(function (response) {
            this.$store.dispatch('getUserDetail');
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
}
```

How can I use the post data to create or update the `request.user`'s profile_picture with Django and django rest framework inside the model viewset class, using default methods (create/update/partial_update) or by creating a new `detail route`?

Comment: are you passing a based64 image?

Comment: if so here is a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28036805/6143656

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab No its not that.

Comment: maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319993/how-to-write-django-rest-api-without-model-to-send-a-file-using-requests

Answer (score 8):

Assuming your JS posts the request using  '`multipart/form-data`' (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37040022/4797469)), you should be able to upload the image file when creating or updating the user. Also, make sure you send [CSRF Token](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/#csrf-protection).

To be able to set the logo on its own, a `detailed_route` is a good way using a serializer limited to the logo.
In the detailed route, if you want to upload log for logged in user (I saw you put `none` as an id), you can check that in the detail route before calling `get_object` which will get the userdetail instance.

```
class UserLogoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserDetail
        fields = ['profile_picture']


class UserDetailViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserDetail.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserDetailSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    @detail_route(methods=['post'])
    def set_profile_picture(self, request, pk=None, format=None):
        if pk in ['none', 'self']: # shortcut to update logged in user without looking for the id
            try:
                userdetail = self.get_queryset().get(user=request.user)
            except UserDetail.DoesNotExist:
                userdetail = None
        else:
            userdetail = self.get_object()

        serializer = serializers.UserLogoSerializer(userdetail, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)            

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

If I recall correctly, `permission_classes` are the one set on the Viewset by default, and the default parsers should do the job.

Answer (score 4):

here is example in official documentation:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser

Comment: How can I use it to post in the model view set?

Comment: @Robin Maybe this post will help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/26766210/5219197